# SQL counting the values from two columns and showing the result in other column at the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table, alter

I have two columns in one table, looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices
(
  ID_Invoice...
  ....
  UnitPrice decimal (15,2) NOT NULL,
  Discount (15,2) NOT NULL,
)
```

So I want to add a new column in this table which count the final price - `UnitPrice`-`Discount=TotalCost`? Please help.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a new computed column to the table that contains that calculation, a new column that contains the value at the time of its creation, or do you just want to select it? mysql *or* sql-server?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, try a calculated column:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices
(
  ID_Invoice...
  ....
  UnitPrice decimal (15,2) NOT NULL,
  Discount (15,2) NOT NULL,
  TotalCost AS UnitPrice - Discount
)
```

If you're using MySQL, your only option is to add a physical column. Don't do that - it denormalizes the table and doesn't bring any benefit. Just query the value on the fly:

```
SELECT
  ID_Invoice,
  UnitPrice,
  Discount,
  UnitPrice - Discount AS TotalCost
```

The MySQL query is simple enough, and by not storing the additional column you don't have to worry about the `TotalCost`, `Discount`, and `UnitPrice` columns getting out of sync.

Comment: MariaDB has calculated columns, too: **[Virtual columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/virtual-columns/)**

Comment: I'm using Sql server so i'll use the first expample you gave.Thanks a lot for the answear, it'll be very usefull for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Alter Table Invoices 
Add TotalCost Decimal(15,2)
```

Will add the column to your table

Now to add values to new column do

```
Update Invoices
set TotalCost = UnitPrice - Discount
```

Please let me know if it works